# Будет ли неопределенный порядок, если LinkedHashMap перевести в ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

`LinkedHashMap` не знает ничего про индексацию. А если я переведу его в `ArrayList` так:

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(linkedHashMap.keySet());
```

То будет ли работать индексация?

Comment: С учетом того, что keySet возвращает Set, я бы не стал полагаться на это, даже если оно работает в текущий момент

Comment: @etki, у меня единственное, это `indexOf` который я вызываю у `ArrayList`. Он может возвращать разные индексы?

Comment: У вас в ArrayList элементы могут приходить в разном порядке, потому что этот самый порядок Set не гарантирует.

Comment: @elik, ааа, это приходить они будут в разном порядке. Но `indexOf` то, работать будет. Хоть и в разном, для меня это не важно. Спасибо!

Comment: @etki вроде документация на `Map` [утверждает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2924143/5661663) что порядок обхода элементов во всех представлениях одинаковый, соотв. итератор по `keySet()` будет возвращать элементы так же, как итератор по `values()` и `entrySet()`.